# Add Image to Part with inline in admin

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to add an item and at the same time add images to this item under the same form.

I have these model classes in my models.py

```
class Part(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=550)

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField()
    part = models.ManyToManyField(Part, related_name='image_part')
```

And I tried to do this is in admin.py

```
    class PartAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        inlines = [        
            ImageInline,
        ]

    class ImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = Image.part.through

admin.site.register(Part, PartAdmin)
```

I get the option to choose image. But it's three dropdowns with images already added to other Parts. I have the add sign. When clicking that, I get to upload images, but with option to choose already added Parts.

Any idea how to add images to a part when creating a new part? Is it even possible?

Comment: Edit: My previous comment was incorrect. But the docs explain this quite nicely: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models

Comment: @BjörnKristinsson I have tried that. But the field is a manytomany and not foreignkey. Therefor I get the fault: __ERRORS:
<class 'part.admin.ImageInline'>: (admin.E202) 'part.Image' has no ForeignKey to 'part.Part'.__

Comment: That&#39;s the documentation I was following. And I can't get it to work.